# Clojure Built in Function to access the entire record

Tags: clojure, record

```
(defrecord Sample (x y))

(def check (Sample. 1 2))

(:x check) ;returns 1
```

If I receive (:x check) as an argument to a function, is there a way to access check? Or, in other words, return

```
#:user.Sample{:x 1, :y 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Óscar described, `(:x check)` won't work because its result is `1`, and `'(:x check)` won't work because its result is a list containing the keyword `:x` and the symbol `check`.

However, instead of using quote you could use the `list` function:

```
(defn receiver [arg]
  (map class arg))

;; With a quoted list it receives the symbol `check` rather
;; than the Sample record
(receiver '(:x check))
;=> (clojure.lang.Keyword clojure.lang.Symbol)

;; But this way it does receive the Sample
(receiver (list :x check))
;=> (clojure.lang.Keyword user.Sample)
```

And `(list :x check)` can be evaluated:

```
(eval (list :x check))
;=> 1

(defn receiver [arg]
  (str "received " arg "; eval'd to: " (eval arg)))

(receiver (list :x check))
;=> "received (:x #user.Sample{:x 1, :y 2}); eval'd to: 1"
```

The reason that [`quote`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28quote%20form%29) and `list` behave so differently is that `quote` doesn't evaluate it's argument. And, when a list is quoted, that effect is recursive: none of the items in the list are evaluated either.

There's another type of quote, called syntax-quote or backquote (and described on the Clojure.org page about the [reader](http://clojure.org/reader)) which allows you to selectively un-quote (i.e. evaluate) items.

```
(require '[clojure.pprint])

(let [n 1
      x :x
      c check]
  (clojure.pprint/pprint
   (vector `(n x c)
           `(~n x c)
           `(~n ~x c)
           `(~n ~x ~c))))
```

Prints:

```
[(user/n user/x user/c)
 (1 user/x user/c)
 (1 :x user/c)
 (1 :x {:x 1, :y 2})]
```

And, actually, I lied a little bit. You could in fact use `'(:x check)` in this particular case. `resolve` will return the `Var` associated with a symbol, and `deref` (or its `@` reader macro) will get you the Var's value.

```
(resolve 'check)
;=> #'user/check

(deref (resolve 'check))
;=> #user.Sample{:x 1, :y 2}

(defn resolve-and-deref-symbols [form]
  (map (fn [x] (if (symbol? x)
                 @(resolve x)
                 x))
       form))

(defn receiver [arg]
  (str "received " arg "; eval'd to: " (eval (resolve-and-deref-symbols arg))))

(receiver '(:x check))
;=> "received (:x check); eval'd to: 1"
```

I didn't mention it straight-away because, while it works easily enough in this example, it's not at all appropriate for the general case. (For instance, it won't work with locals, and handling namespaces and nested data structure would be painful).

Answer (score 4):

No, if a function is passed `(:x check)` as parameter then the value was already evaluated *before* entering the function, you'll just receive a `1` as value, and you can't retrieve the record it came from.

If you need the record inside the function, why don't you pass `check` as parameter?

Comment: If I pass '(:x check) instead; is there still no way? For instance, I know that the "#_" reader macro can skip an evaluation. (concat #_(list (+ 1 2)) (list (+ 1 1))) will return (2) instead of (3 2). Is there anything similar in clojure for the problem I stated?

Comment: (I understand I can just pass check, but if instead I pass an evaluation, I was just wondering if it is possible to "back-trace" in a sense)

Comment: If you pass `'(:x check)` that'll just be a list of symbols inside the function, with no way to "back trace" to the fact that `check` was a record before calling the function

Comment: Since `check` is a `Var` you can use `resolve`/`deref` to get to its value - `(deref (resolve 'check))` => `#user.Sample{:x 1, :y 2}`. I included some more info in an answer below.